# Tasker service still want to start after uninstalling it

Tags: tasker, logging

Here is a warning from my Logcat

> 07:04:44.099 ActivityManager( 1143)  Unable to start service Intent {
>   act=android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService
>   cmp=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm/.NotificationListenerService } U=0:
>   not found

I unistalled Tasker a few months ago.
Why is there still a call to start a service?

Comment: I incidentally downloaded "Settings Database Editor" (by4a.setedit22) and found in "Secure Table" a reference to Tasker notification. So I deleted it. I also found a lot of ES file browser (+ Baidu) references (also uninstalled some months ago), deleted them too.